# Shared memory API, where a process can attach shared memory to other process

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

Can any one look into this and suggest me with an API.

We have APIs for a process which can create and/or attach a shared memory to its own process. But I don't find an API to attach a shared memory to one process by other process(for e.g., process A should call one API(like shmat()) to attach the shared memory to process B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared memory doesn't belong to *any* particular process (unless you create it with a private `IPC_PRIVATE` key). It belongs to the system.

So, when you use `shmget` with a non-private key (and the `IPC_CREAT` flag), you will either create a shared memory block or attach to an existing one.

You need a way for both processes to use the same IPC key and this is often done by using `ftok` which uses a file specification and an identifier to give you an IPC key for use in the `shmget` call (and other IPC type calls, such as `msgget` or `semget`).

For example, in the programs `pax1` and `pax2`, you may have a code segment like:

```
int getMyShMem (void) {
    key_t mykey = ftok ("/var/pax.cfg", 0); // only one shm block so use id of 0
    if (mykey == (key_t)-1)                 // no go.
        return -1;
    return shmget (mykey, 1024, IPC_CREAT); // get (or make) a 1K block.
}
```

By having both processes use the same file specification and ID, they'll get the same shared memory block.

You can use different IDs to give you distinct shared memory blocks all based on the same file (you may, for example, want one for a configuration shared memory block and another for storing shared state).

And, given that it's *your* configuration file the IPC key is based on, the chances of other programs using it is minuscule (I think it may be zero but I'm not 100% sure).

You can't forcefully inject shared memory into a process from outside that process (well, you may be able to but it would be both dangerous and require all sorts of root-level permissions). That would break the protected process model and turn you system into something about as secure as MS-DOS :-)

Comment: if we want to use shared memory for a particular process, we need to call shmget() or shmat() in the same process code. However I want an API which can be called from a process to attach the shared memory to other process. the same I explained above. Could any one have the related APIs, please suggest.

Comment: @candy. It's the same API. It's called shared memory because it's _shared!_ More generally, it's called IPC because it's _inter_ process (between processes). You just use `shmget` with the same IPC key (and `IPC_CREAT` if you're not sure it will already exist) and both processes will be looking at the same memory. Forcing shared memory into process A from process B, I've never seen an API for that (and with good reason).

Comment: I know that we can use shmget for sharing among no.of process, what exactly I want is.. "I will call shmget() (or any related API), from process A, but I want it to be attached to process B" do you have any such APIs

Comment: thats fine,thnks' I will try for APIs by following security issues

Comment: Windows actually *does* have ways for process A to gain access to the (non-shared) memory space of process B.  Presumably they implemented that to make things easier for the password-stealers, virus authors, etc.  :^P  I'd be surprised if Linux had a similar facility though.

Comment: @Jeremy, you can do that with Linux provided you have the right permissions. You can get direct access to things like `/dev/mem` physical memory and `/dev/kmem` kernel virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, allow one process to force a shared memory segment on to another? What is the receiver going to do with it? How will it know it now has mapped this block in - what is expected of it.

You're thinking about the problem the wrong way - simply hoisting a block of memory on to a second process is not going to allow you to do what you want. You need to notify the second process also that it has now mapped this block and so can start doing stuff with it. I suggest you take a step back and really look at your design and what you are doing. My recommended approach would be

1. A connects to B via some other IPC (say socket)
2. A informs B that it should attach with the details (name etc.)
3. B then attaches - and now B is aware of it and can start doing stuff with it. (say for example once the attach completes, B confirms to A, and then they can start talking over the shared memory block).

As for wrapping shared memory in a nice library - consider boost::interprocess.

Comment: see the attaching functionality not to be done by the B process, It should done by A(means to attaching SHared memory to process B),the shared memory address I can send it through some IPC.say SOCKET, attachement is done. I want to know to know is there any API to attach shared memory to process B bycalling attach function(eg.,shmat()) in process A. as we know shmat() will attach shm to its own process. thats not the actual intention

Comment: @candy why? if you are going to propagate all the information that B needs anyway?

Comment: I want to use shared memory in my process, I don't want to do(call l APIs) any creating/attaching functionalities in my process, I want the other process to do this for me(my process). so broadly the other process should act like a Shared memory organiser for my process. It just has to give me the SHM Address, this is what is my actual requirement

Comment: @candy, good luck looking for such a thing... IMHO, it's a totally redundant complication given you have to do 1-3 above anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to attach the *process memory* of other process, right?

Just `open(2)` the file `/proc/<pid>/mem` and use it. Check the `/proc/<pid>/map` for the list of usable address in the file.

Comment: I am talking about SHARED MEMORY, not the process memory space